# How "subsets" and "embedding" differs?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, notation, lp-spaces

If $A\subset B,$ we may write $A\hookrightarrow B$ (According to this notion of Inclusion map).

> My Questions: (1)If we have the notation  $\subset$ (subset), then why do we need the notation $\hookrightarrow $ (Embedding)? How these two notations differs?  If $A\hookrightarrow B$, then can we say $A\subset B$? (example?)
>   (2) Sometimes authors says that the imbedding $A\hookrightarrow B$
>    is compact? What does this mean? (3) Is $\ell^{1}(\mathbb Z) \hookrightarrow \ell^{\infty}(\mathbb Z)$ is a compact embedding?

Comment: An [Embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding) is something more : it is "structure-preserving".

Comment: The notation for embedding means that the topology of the space is in some sense inherited  by the subspace. In other words, if a sequence in the subspace converges (based on the topology of the subspace), then it also converges in the space itself (on the topology defined on the space).

Answer (score 5):

Given a subset $A \subset B$, the inclusion map $i : A \hookrightarrow B$ is an embedding.

Also, given a general embedding $f : A \hookrightarrow B$, its image $f(A)$ is a subset of $B$. However, $A$ itself in general is *not* a subset of $B$, and it should not be "thought of" as a subset of $B$ (despite what wikipedia says).

For example, the interval $[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ may be embedded (topologically) into $\mathbb{R}^2$ by the function
$$f(t) = (3t-7,-6t+22)
$$
and its image is the line segment $L=\overline{PQ} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with endpoints $P=(-7,22)$ and $Q=(-4,16)$. However, that does not mean that we should think of $[0,1]$ and $L$ as "the same thing"; they are simply "isomorphic things".

Comment: Please consider (politely) editing the wikipedia page.

Comment: Hmm no I don't think so. The closed unit interval and $L$ *are* the same thing, if we are in $\underline{Top}$.

Comment: @user259242 No, that's not true. Even in the category of topological spaces, they are different (although isomorphic) objects. This is admittedly an [evil](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence) distinction to make, but it is real nonetheless.

Comment: If isomorphic objects are not 'the same', then well I don't know what are! But yes, you are right. I suppose its a matter of taste in a way.

Comment: But you *do* know when two objects are the same. Two mathematical objects realized as sets $A,B$ are the same if for all $x$, $x \in A \iff x \in B$.